# Cannot open CSV file using OLEDB

Tags: c#

I have created a program that can open excel file, but the code I use does not open CSV file.
The full code is:

```cs
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm; *.csv";

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
    txtPath.Text = ofd.FileName;
}

string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + txtPath.Text + "';Extended Properties= \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\";";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
con.Open();

cmbSheet.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
cmbSheet.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
cmbSheet.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";

OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + cmbSheet.SelectedValue + "]", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows){
    dgv.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you try this code?

Comment: Check the version of ACE installed on PC : C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado12.dll.  Make version in connection string same as version on PC.  ACE comes with Microsoft Office and if you do not have Office installed on PC you need to install the runtime version of ADO on machine.

Comment: To ADyson.
When I try to open an excel file for example xlsx, it can open fine. But when I try to open the CSV file, the message comes: "External table is not in the expected format."

Comment: To jdweng.
There is no msado12.dll on my PC. There are these on my PC:
msado15,20,21,25,26,27,28,60. I couldn't find it online. I don't know much about this. Do you have any suggestions or other options?